# Approximating $\pi$ using Monte Carlo integration

Tags: integration, approximation, pi, monte-carlo

I need to estimate $\pi$ using the following integration:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \!\sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx$$

using monte carlo

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please note that I'm a student trying to learn this stuff so if you can please please be more indulging and try to explain in depth..

Comment: could it be a typografic error? You have $$ \frac{\pi}{4} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $$

Comment: Yes!! can you explain how you reached that answer?

Comment: A picture may help. $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ gives the unit circle; if $y \ge 0$ and $x \in [0, 1]$, then we can rewrite this as $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. The unit circle has area $\pi * 1^2 = \pi$, and we're taking just the upper right quarter of it.

Comment: Perhaps see `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/` for more on Monte Carlo integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generate a sequence $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ of independent uniform$[0,1]$ random variables. 
Let $Y_i = f(U_i)$, where $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Then, for sufficiently large $n$,
$$
\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {Y_i } }}{n} \approx \int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x = } \int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 - x^2 } \,{\rm d}x}  = \frac{\pi }{4}.
$$

**EDIT**: Elaborating.

Suppose that $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of independent uniform$[0,1]$ random variables, and $f$ is an integrable function on $[0,1]$, that is, $\int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,{\rm d}x}  < \infty$. Then, the (finite) integral $\int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x}$ can be approximated as follows. Let $Y_i = f(U_i)$, so the $Y_i$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, with mean (expectation) $\mu$ given by
$$
\mu = {\rm E}[Y_1] = {\rm E}[f(U_1)] = \int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x}.
$$
By the strong law of large numbers, the average $\bar Y_n  = \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {Y_i } }}{n}$ converges, with probability $1$, to the expectation $\mu$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, with probability $1$, $\bar Y_n  \to \int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x}$ as $n \to \infty$.

To get a probabilistic error bound, suppose further that $f$ is square-integrable on $[0,1]$, that is $
\int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,{\rm d}x}  < \infty $. Then, the $Y_i$ have finite variance, $\sigma_2$, given by
$$
\sigma^2 = {\rm Var}[Y_1] = {\rm E}[Y_1^2] - {\rm E}^2{[Y_1]} = {\rm E}[f^2{(U_1)}] - {\rm E}^2{[f(U_1)]} = 
\int_0^1 {f^2 (x) \,{\rm d}x}  - \bigg[\int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x} \bigg]^2 .
$$ 
By linearity of expectation, the average $\bar Y_n $ has expectation 
$$
{\rm E}[\bar Y_n] = \mu.
$$
Since the $Y_i$ are independent, $\bar Y_n $ has variance
$$
{\rm Var}[\bar Y_n] = {\rm Var}\bigg[\frac{{Y_1  +  \cdots  + Y_n }}{n}\bigg] = \frac{1}{{n^2 }}{\rm Var}[Y_1  +  \cdots  + Y_n ] = \frac{n}{{n^2 }}{\rm Var}[Y_1 ] = \frac{{\sigma ^2 }}{n}.
$$ 
By Chebyshev's inequality, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
{\rm P}\big[\big|\bar Y_n - {\rm E}[\bar Y_n]\big| \geq \varepsilon \big] \leq \frac{{{\rm Var}[\bar Y_n]}}{{\varepsilon ^2 }},
$$
so
$$
{\rm P}\big[\big|\bar Y_n - \mu \big| \geq \varepsilon \big] \leq \frac{{\sigma^2}}{{n \varepsilon ^2 }},
$$
and hence
$$
{\rm P}\bigg[\bigg|\bar Y_n -  \int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x} \bigg| \geq \varepsilon \bigg] \leq \frac{1}{{n \varepsilon ^2 }} \bigg \lbrace \int_0^1 {f^2 (x) \,{\rm d}x}  - \bigg[\int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x} \bigg]^2 \bigg \rbrace.
$$
So if $n$ is sufficiently large, with high probability the absolute difference between $\bar Y_n$ and $\int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x}$ will be smaller than $\varepsilon$.

Returning to your specific question, letting $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ thus gives
$$
{\rm P}\Big[\Big|\bar Y_n - \frac{\pi }{4} \Big| \geq \varepsilon \Big] \leq \frac{1}{{n \varepsilon ^2 }} \bigg \lbrace \int_0^1 {(1 - x^2) \,{\rm d}x}  -  \frac{\pi^2 }{16} \bigg \rbrace  = \frac{1}{{n \varepsilon ^2 }} \bigg \lbrace  \frac{2}{3} -  \frac{\pi^2 }{16} \bigg \rbrace < \frac{1}{{20n\varepsilon ^2 }},
$$
where $\bar Y_n  = \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {\sqrt {1 - U_i^2 } } }}{n}$.

Comment: How did you get from that integration to \frac{\pi }{4}. ? My math is very rusty..

Comment: See http://forums.randi.org/archive/index.php/t-36118.html

Comment: on the link abose they get (x/2)sqrt(1-x^2) + Arcsin(x)/2 how did you get \frac{\pi }{4}. ?

Comment: Let $F(x)=(x/2)\sqrt{1-x^2} + \arcsin(x)/2$. Note that $F(1)-F(0) = \arcsin(1)/2 = \pi/4$.

Comment: You generate $n$ independent uniform$[0,1]$ random variables, $U_1,\ldots,U_n$, and for each $i=1,\ldots,n$, let $Y_i = \sqrt{1-U_i^2}$. Then the average $(Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n)/n$ approximates $\pi / 4$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Concerning the evaluation of the integral, note that $\int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 - x^2 } \,{\rm d}x}$ gives the area under the curve $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, hence equal to $\pi/4$.

Comment: wow.. awesome Shai... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let's also elaborate on Ross Millikan's answer, adapted to the case $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Suppose that $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\ldots$ is a sequence of independent uniform vectors on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, so that for each $i$, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent uniform$[0,1]$ random variables. Define $Z_i$ as follows: $Z_i = 1$ if $X_i^2 + Y_i^2 \leq 1$, $Z_i = 0$ if $X_i^2 + Y_i^2 > 1$, so the $Z_i$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, with mean $\mu$ given by
$$
\mu = {\rm E}[Z_1] = {\rm P}[X_1^2 + Y_1^2 \leq 1] = {\rm P}\big[(X_1,Y_1) \in \lbrace (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1\rbrace \big] = \frac{\pi }{4}, 
$$
where the last equality follows from ${\rm P}[(X_1,Y_1) \in A] = {\rm area}A$ ($A \subset [0,1]^2$).

By the strong law of large numbers, the average $\bar Z_n  = \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {Z_i } }}{n}$ converges, with probability $1$, to the expectation $\mu$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, with probability $1$, $\bar Z_n  \to \frac{\pi }{4}$ as $n \to \infty$.

To get a probabilistic error bound, note first that the $Z_i$ have variance $\sigma^2$ given by
$$
\sigma^2 = {\rm Var}[Z_1] = {\rm E}[Z_1^2] - {\rm E}^2{[Z_1]} = \frac{\pi }{4} - \Big(\frac{\pi }{4}\Big)^2 = \frac{\pi }{4} \Big(1 - \frac{\pi }{4}\Big) < \frac{10}{59}.
$$
The average $\bar Z_n $ has expectation ${\rm E}[\bar Z_n] = \mu$ and variance ${\rm Var}[\bar Z_n] = \sigma^2 / n$; hence, by Chebyshev's inequality, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
{\rm P}\big[\big|\bar Z_n - \mu \big| \geq \varepsilon \big] \leq \frac{{\sigma^2}}{{n \varepsilon ^2 }},
$$
and so
$$
{\rm P}\bigg[\bigg|\bar Z_n - \frac{\pi }{4}  \bigg| \geq \varepsilon \bigg] < \frac{{10}}{{59n\varepsilon ^2 }}.
$$

Comment: I'll definitely have to review my math!!

Answer (score 2):

No longer applicable as the integral has been corrected:  I don't understand how this integral gets you $\pi$ and if you pull the $x$ out you get $\int_0^1x\sqrt{10}dx=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$

The general idea  of a Monte Carlo integration of $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is to take random pairs $(x,y)$ with $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le y \le y_{max}$ and check for how many of the pairs $f(x)\le y$.  The integral is then the number of pairs under the curve divided by the number of trials and multiplied by the area of the box ($x y_{max}$)

Comment: hey i am very sorry i misspelled (first time using the alfabet) it's actually sqrt (1-x^2) inside the integration

Comment: So  i need to make a c++ program that simulates this. i would random generate x from 0 to 1  and y from 0 to lets say 10.000 (the higher the more accurate).. do the math for f(x) an check f(x)<= y. Good. bu how do i relate to pi?

Comment: y would run from 0 to 1-you just need it to be big enough to be greater than f(x) for all x.  So you would generate lots (say 10,000) pairs (x,y) in the unit square and count how many have y<sqrt(1-x^2).  Presumably this is about 7850.  The area would be 7850/10000 and multiplying by 4 gives your measurement of pi.

Comment: i'm missing something here:             int x = 0;

            int y = 0;

            int k = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                x = new Random().Next(0, 1);
                y = new Random().Next(0, 1);

                if (y < Math.Sqrt(1 - x * x))
                    k++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Pi={0}", (k/10000)*4);

Comment: @Zapacila:  I don't read C very well, but with k an int, doesn't dividing by 10000 give 0?

Comment: @Ross in was actually c# i also posted the source code below in case anyone else needs it

Answer (score 1):

C# implementation. Thanks to all who contributed!! Ross,  Esteban, Shai

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 0;
        var rd = new Random();

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) // the higher the more precise
        {
            x = rd.NextDouble();
            sum += Math.Sqrt(1 - x*x); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Pi={0}", (sum/1000000)*4);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Later on, I'll give a probabilistic error bound. I hope you'll find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks Shai for you devotion to the subject. I'm most interested since i have a project based on this. Please don't forget to share lots of details.Again Thanks!

Comment: google searchable: sqrt(1-x^2) dx pi estimate integration algorithm